# Enable logging on Samsung Galaxy Note II without adb

Tags: android, logging, galaxy, samsung-mobile

Is there any option how to enable log on this device? On other devices we have "Take bug report" option in developer options , but on NoteII this option is missing. (The developer options is visible). We have try everything (alogcat, press power+volume button).

Comment: I have this exact problem, it may be a limitation of the Note 2.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](http://www.technipages.com/android-developer-options-is-missing.html), you will need to do the followings:

> If you’ve found that the Developer Options selecting is missing from the Settings of your Android device, it’s probably because you have version 4.2 (JellyBean) of the Android OS. The option is now hidden and has to be enabled first.
>
> 1. Open the Settings app.
> 2. Scroll down to the bottom and select About phone or About tablet.
> 3. Scroll down to the bottom and tap Build number repeatedly. A message should appear on the screen that says “You are now 4 steps
>      away from being a developer.” Keep tapping until it says “You are now
>      a developer.”
>
> [image]
>   4. Now back on the main Settings screen, Developer Options should appear as a selection.

If you are using an older version of android for siii then followw [Samsung Galaxy S3: Enable/Disable USB Debugging](http://www.technipages.com/samsung-galaxy-s3-enabledisable-usb-debugging.html) .